# I need to turn a series of commands piped together into an alias in .bashrc

Tags: bash, quoting, alias, bashrc

```
sudo ifconfig wlan0 | grep 'inet addr:' | cut -d: -f2 | awk '{ print $1}'
```

The above command when run from terminal outputs the right "internal" ip address. When I try to pass as alias like:

```
alias intip='sudo ifconfig wlan0 | grep 'inet addr:' | cut -d: -f2 | awk '{ print $1}''
```

I am getting the following error:

```
alias: addr: | cut -d: -f2 | awk { not found
alias: print not found
alias: } not found
```

What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: The alias end as `grep `.  Use 'quotes "inside" quotes' or use "quotes 'inside' quotes" to address this.

Comment: There is no reason to use `sudo` for this, FYI. At least not on Linux. You just need the path: `/sbin/ifconfig` (`/sbin` is not in non-root users' paths by default)

Comment: Its not a regular pc situation. Its Nokia N900 with the Maemo Operating system where the regular user has no access to ifconfig and other utils ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A matter of using double quotes and single quotes where it matters:

```
alias lsa="ls -l | awk '{print \$1}' "
```

Comment: ;-) Great, glad you made it

Answer (score 3):

What you're doing wrong is using an alias for something that's more complicated than giving a shorter name to a command or passing parameters to a command automatically. Use a function instead, and you won't have to worry about quoting.

```
intip () {
    /sbin/ifconfig wlan0 | grep 'inet addr:' | cut -d: -f2 | awk '{ print $1}'
}
```

Note that you don't need sudo here, `ifconfig` doesn't need privileges when you're only looking. But on many distributions you need to provide the full path as `ifconfig` is often not in the default `PATH` for non-root users.

By the way, you can do your filtering entirely in awk, though feel free to use multiple tools if you're more comfortable that way. Here's one way:

```
intip () {
    /sbin/ifconfig wlan0 | awk 'sub(/^.*inet addr:/,"") {sub(/ .*/,""); print}'
}
```

You can easily make the interface name an optional parameter of the function.

```
intip () {
    /sbin/ifconfig "${1:-wlan0}" |
    awk 'sub(/^.*inet addr:/,"") {sub(/ .*/,""); print}'
}
```

---

Just to show why your alias doesn't work: you have single quotes both to delimit the alias and inside the alias text. The interpreter can't read your mind and see which ones were meant to be which. See [Calling bash from sh (dash) with commands read from args, and "Unterminated quoted string"/"unexpected EOF"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/73219/calling-bash-from-sh-dash-with-commands-read-from-args-and-unterminated-quot/73492#73492) for some quotes-inside-quotes cases and [Why is echo ignoring my quote characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24647/why-is-echo-ignoring-my-quote-characters/24676#24676) for how to effectively include a single quote in a single-quoted string by entering the four characters `'\''`.

Answer (score 2):

Or you could install [`moreutils`](http://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/) (at least, if its available for your distro) and use `ifdata`.

```
$ ifdata -pa br0
172.16.1.244
```

You'd use wlan0 instead of br0, of course.

Comment: Wow, I had no idea this was in moreutils.  Thanks!  However, nowadays it seems `ifconfig` is deprecated on most systems in favor of the newer `ip` command, but I don't know much more about it than that.

Comment: @jw013 `ip` has many, many more features—required in advanced networking—than ifconfig, which is why the later is obsolete. But `ifdata` isn't actually using ifconfig, at least not for getting the interface address. Its using `ioctl(SIOCGIFADDR, …)`